# How can I use re.sub with IGNORECASE in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to modify a string with the help of `re.sub`:

```
>>> re.sub("sparta", r"<b>\1</b>", "Here is Sparta.", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

I expect to get:

```
'Here is <b>Sparta</b>.'
```

But I get an error instead:

```
>>> re.sub("sparta", r"<b>\1</b>", "Here is Sparta.", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 291, in filter
    return sre_parse.expand_template(template, match)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 833, in expand_template
    raise error, "invalid group reference"
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference
```

How should I use `re.sub` to get the correct result?

Comment: Or use `'(sparta)'` as the pattern, so there is a capturing group.

Comment: Could you, please, provide the full code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks a lot. It worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not specify any capturing group in the pattern and use a backreference to Group 1 in the replacement pattern. That causes an issue.

Either define a capturing group in the pattern and use the appropriate backreference in the replacement pattern, or use the `\g<0>` backreference to the whole match:

```
re.sub("sparta", r"<b>\g<0></b>", "Here is Sparta.", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/nZo3H9).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `\x` in your second string (replacement string I think it's called) where `x` is a number, python is going to replace it with the group `x`.

You can define a group in your regex by wrapping it with parentheses, like so:

```
re.sub(r"capture (['me]{2})", r'group 1: \1', 'capture me!') # => group 1: me
re.sub(r"capture (['me]{2})", r'group 1: \1', "capture 'em!") # => group 1: 'em
```

> Nested captures? I've lost the count!

It's the *opening* bracket that defines it's number:

```
(this is the first group (this is the second) (this is the third))
```

#### *Named* group

Named group are pretty useful when you use the match object that returns `re.match` or `re.search`
for example (refer to the [docs](http://devdocs.io/python~3.5/library/re#match-objects) for more), but also when you use complex regex, because they bring *clarity*.

You can name a group with the following syntax:

```
(?P<your_group_name>your pattern)
```

So, for example:

```
re.sub("(?P<first>hello(?P<second>[test]+)) (?P<third>[a-z])", "first: \g<first>") # => first: hello
```

#### What is the group `0`

The group `0` is the entire match. But, you can't use `\0`, because it's going to print out `\x00` (the actual value of this escaped code). The solution is to use the *named group* syntax (because regular group are kind of named group: they're name is just an integer): `\g<0>`. So, for example:

```
re.sub(r'[hello]+', r'\g<0>', 'lehleo') # => lehleo
```

#### For your problem

This answer is just suppose to explain capturing, not really answering your question, since [@Wiktor Stribiżew's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42181227/6164984) is perfect.